# amazon s3 download file signed url IE 11 and Edge doesn't download as attachment

Tags: amazon-s3

I have the following  code but doesn't download the large file in browser progress bar; it just looks like it is loading forever. Works fine in all browsers except any Microsoft browser. This is an exe file.

```
    require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';

    $s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => 'us-east-1'
    ]);

    $cmd = $s3->getCommand('GetObject', [
        'Bucket' => 'download.phppointofsale.com',
        'Key'    => $filename,
            'ResponseContentDisposition' => 'attachment',
            'ResponseContentType' => 'application/octet-stream'
    ]);

    $request = $s3->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');

    // Get the actual presigned-url
    $presignedUrl = (string) $request->getUri();
    header('Location: '.$presignedUrl);
```

Answer (score 4):

I suddenly had the same issue, after it had been working fine for years.

I tracked it down to Windows Defender SmartScreen, which is active in Edge by default. As soon as I deactivate it, the download works fine.

The setting can be found here:

1. Open Edge settings.
2. Scroll to the bottom and click on **View advanced settings** button
3. Scroll to the bottom again and deactivate setting **Help protect me from malicious sites and downloads with Windows Defender SmartScreen**.

It seems like this is a known issue in Edge and has been confirmed by the  Microsoft Edge team: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/12166637/